# Best way to switch back and forth between two variables when switched swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a variable, gameMode, that I would like to switch between Vertical and Horizontal whenever the screen is tapped. The issue that I am having is that it only takes the lower variable and the gameMode always displays as Horizontal. How could I fix this so that it switches whenever the touchesBegan method is called? Any help is appreciated!

Here is the code for the issue I am having:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    if gameMode == "Horizontal" {

        gameMode = "Vertical"

    }


    if gameMode == "Vertical" {

        gameMode = "Horizontal"

    }


    print(gameMode) }
```

Comment: This may be what you're looking for https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/StateMachine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015172-CH7-SW1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because if `gameMode` is `"Horizontal"`, you set `gameMode` to `"Vertical"` and after this `gameMode == "Vertical"` returns `true`, so you set `gameMode` to `"Horizontal"`.

Try this code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if gameMode == "Horizontal" {

        gameMode = "Vertical"
    } else {
        gameMode = "Horizontal"
    }

    print(gameMode)
}
```

You should use `enum` instead of Strings.

Example:

```
enum GameMode {
    case horizontal
    case vertical

    mutating func toggle() {
        self = self == .horizontal ? .vertical : .horizontal
    }
}

var gameMode: GameMode = .horizontal

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    gameMode.toggle()
    print(gameMode)
}
```

Comment: You could also make a mutating func toggle() on that enum for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the two states with the ternary operator

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    gameMode = gameMode == "Horizontal" ? "Vertical" : "Horizontal"
    print(gameMode) 
}
```

For only two states maybe a boolean variable is more suitable. If `gameMode` was `Bool` you can simply write

```
gameMode = !gameMode
```

Comment: gameMode - is bad name for Bool value. As for me, isHorizontal or isVertical will be better. But the best way to implement it - use enum GameMode.

Comment: It's up to the developer to use a reasonable name. It's just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I would replace

```
if gameMode == "Horizontal" {

    gameMode = "Vertical"

}


if gameMode == "Vertical" {

    gameMode = "Horizontal"

}
```

with

```
if gameMode == "Horizontal" {

    gameMode = "Vertical"

} else {

    gameMode = "Horizontal"

}
```

With two *if* statements in a row, when you send "Horizontal" as, the value, it will switch it to "Vertical". That will also make the second statement kick in and switch it back. Using an if/else will make sure that it only runs once.